# Mapstruct: custom mapping int to CharSeq Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, type-conversion, mapping, mapstruct

I am writing a mapper using MapStruct with Spring Boot and I currently am struggling with a mapping to map an int field to a CharSeq field:

I tried the following:

```
@Mapping(
     target = "target.id", // Type Charseq
     source = "source.id", // Type int
     qualifiedBy = MappingHelper.IntToCharSeq.class
)
```

And I have a mapping Helper with the following code:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MappingHelper {
    @Qualifier
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface IntToCharSeq {
    }

    @IntToCharSeq
    public CharSequence intToCharSeq(int input) {
        return (CharSequence) String.valueOf(input);
    }
}
```

However when I try to package the Spring Boot application and mapstruct is run, I have the following error message:

```
[ERROR] /C:/Users/[...]/Mapper.java:[82,45] Can't map property "int target.id" to "java.lang.CharSequence source.id". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "java.lang.CharSequence map(int value)".
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work and what can I do to make it work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How does the definition for your mapper look like? i.e. how does `@Mapper` look like

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, it looks like this:

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it doesn't work is because your mapper does not have the `MappingConfig` in the `Mapper#uses`

You'll need to tell MapStruct to look for it.

e.g.

```
@Mapper(uses = MappingConfig.class) 
public interface MyMapper {

    // Your mapping code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Exampe looks as follows

```
@MapperConfig(
    unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR,
    componentModel = "spring",
    collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED,
    builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true)
)
public class MappingConfig {
}
```

Dummy Class with Integer

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DummyTwo {

  private int name;

}
```

Dummy Class with CharSequence

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DummyOne {

    private CharSequence name;

}
```

The Mapper

```
@Mapper(config = MappingConfig.class)
public interface TestMapper {


    DummyOne mapTo(DummyTwo dummyTwo);


    default CharSequence intToCharSequenze(int someInt){
        String s = String.valueOf(someInt);
        return s;
    }
}
```

[image]

You can use CharSequence, but there is no reason not to use a String

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I thought about using the defaut method but I'm using an abtract class because I have an after mapping method, sorry I totally forgot to mention that. Anyway I think that you are right in the sense that external mapper may not be the best solution here